# I m geting an error like this "Expected a value of type 'List<Dynamic>',but got one of type 'Null' " in brower.I want to get a json file readed

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // this function is called before the build so that
    // the string assettoload is avialable to the DefaultAssetBuilder
    setasset();
    // and now we return the FutureBuilder to load and decode JSON
    return FutureBuilder(
      future:
          DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString(assettoload, cache: false),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        List mydata = jsonDecode(snapshot.data.toString());
        if (mydata == null) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text(
                "Loading",
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return quizpage(mydata: mydata);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I was expecting to get output in the browser which i passed in json format but it returned error

Comment: Please reformat your code as it's not readable right now.

Comment: i suggest you to update the last version of flutter, and use the [null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety) of dart

Comment: Please show full error log to identify the location of the error.